# Cannot login as root in openSUSE subsystem of windows 10

Tags: windows-10, opensuse

[Update: The problem was, that I logged in with another user account. See answer.]

I lost my root/admin password for the suse subsystem of windows 10. How can I reset it?

There exist several guides for ubuntu. However, I saw only ubuntu specific.

I tried `lxrun /setdefaultuser root`and got

```
Warning: lxrun.exe is only used to configure the legacy Windows Subsystem for Linux distribution.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Windows Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore

Error: 0x80070002
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the sudo command again: I had installed openSUSE by a local user. Nowadays I work with another (company) account under windows. I was able to regain control of the system by using the local account, login into openSUSE bash subsystem (same openSUSE user as I also work with under the company account). There I was able to use the password I once was sure to know.